# ZeroBrane Studio runtime error with tab right-click menu "Save As..."

Tags: lua, runtimeexception, zerobrane

Right-clicking a tab in ZeroBrane Studio (1.90; MobDebug 0.706) and choosing "Save as..." gives (after entering a new name and clicking Save on the "Save file as" dialog) me the following runtime exception:
[image: ZeroBrane Studio runtime error with tab right-click menu "Save As..."]

This does not happen if I use "Save as..." from the main menu, only from the menu that appears on right-clicking a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already [reported earlier](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/1077) and [fixed in the master branch](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/01fda26c1c692fdc4f36d36f5616f0ca04e8b0db). You may want to get the most recent code from that branch or just apply the fix from the commit I referenced.